# Android EPUBLIB read/load content

Tags: android, epub, epublib

I'm playing with http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib on Android. Can someone please explain the right way to

- read epub HTML content,
- how to show this on Android (using WebView?),
- how to split content into pages and
- how to search the content.

Thx 10x.

Comment: Have you found a viable solution?

Answer (score 7):

Answers #2:

1. Extract epub on file system /mnt/sdcard/epub/
2. Loading values in webview

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    setContentView(R.layout.epub_reader);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(new FileInputStream(filename);
    String baseUrl="file://mnt/sdcard/epub/OEBPS/"
    String data = new String(book.getContents().get(2).getData());
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

Comment: How to display images without extracting?

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your questions:

#### How to read epub HTML content

I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want all the content? Or something specific?
All the content can be retrieved using `Book.getContent()`.

#### how to show this on Android (using WebView?),

I would use `WebView` for this. Haven't tried that myself though.

#### how to split content into pages

This I don't know what would work best.

#### how to search the content.

The `nl.siegmann.epublib.search` package in epublib-tools has code for a simple search functionality.

Comment: can you provide the library link for search content.