# why epublib for android web view load data url show [B@41408d8?

Tags: java, android, epublib

Hi everyone i try to show content of epub using epublib.
this is my code

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/documents/cindersilly.epub");
            String path = f.getPath();

            FileInputStream epubInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
            Book book = new EpubReader().readEpub(epubInputStream);

            wvTest.loadDataWithBaseURL(f.getAbsolutePath(), book.getContents().get(0).getData().toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

and i get result :

> [B@41408d8

what is that?
and how to solve this so the content will show on the webview?
thanks

Comment: What do you think it should return and why? What is `getData`? What does `toString()` do?

Comment: i try recode from this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038228/android-epublib-read-load-content, but this solution not work for me

Comment: I don't see you doing what they did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted enough code to be able to see all the details, but your `getData()` method is returning a `byte[]`. When you invoke `toString()` on an object, it tries to convert it into a `String`; but arrays don't have a `toString()` that returns anything particularly useful. What you get is a header (`[B`) that tells you its type (byte array), and an address that says where in JVM memory it's stored.

If you want to be able to see the contents of the array, you can use `Arrays.toString()` to turn it into something more useful. You pass it the `byte[]` you've got (in this case, the output of `getData()`) and it constructs the `String` representation for you. Your code would look like this:

```
wvTest.loadDataWithBaseURL(f.getAbsolutePath(), Arrays.toString(book.getContents().get(0).getData()), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

It's also possible you weren't intending it to return a `byte[]` at all, in which case your problem is further back in your code.

Comment: The `byte[]` is probably the content. They probably want to construct a `String` object from it, `new String(getData(), someEncoding)`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, that's my guess too. I suspect that once OP sees the contents in a more obvious form, he'll be better placed to work out what he wants to do with it.

Comment: woah you are right, i think .toString() and new String("") are same, but i was wrong, thanks